# useEffect reading array outside of it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So let's say I have the following array of strings:

```
const types = [
    "type1",
    "type2",
    "type3" ]
```

And then I also have a useEffect hook like this:

```
useEffect( () => {
    if (someOtherString in types) { doSomething...}
}, [someOtherString])
```

The problem with the above useEffect hook is that it will ask to add dependecy on "types" variable. So if I add it to the dependency list:

`,[someOtherString, types])`

It will re-render for about 3 or 4 times.

How can you create a useEffect that can read an array or a dictionary, which is defined outside of it, without adding it to dependencies?

Comment: You could move `types` outside your component. Also I guess `in` doesn't do what you want to ...

Comment: Is `types` declared outside the component?

Comment: So, you're wondering about an ESlint warning, not the code not actually working?

Comment: Yes, im wondering about an ESling warning. The code is working.

Comment: types is declared inside component

Answer (score 0):

How about having as dependency the condition itself?
Example:

```js
const shouldDoSomething = someOtherString in types;

useEffect(() => {
  if (shouldDoSomething) { /** Do something ! */ }
}, [shouldDoSomething])
```